# POST regular JSON to custom RestResource

Tags: 8

So I created my own `RestResource`, like so:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource to get/create content data.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "mycontent_content",
 *   label = @Translation("My content"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/content/{type}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/api/content/{type}"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ContentResource extends ResourceBase {

    public function get($type) {
        // Works
    }

    public function post($type) {
        // Doesn't work
    }
}
```

`GET` works fine, but I can not post a regular JSON object.

With the content-type set to `application/json` I always get this error:

```
{
    "error": "Could not denormalize object of type , no supporting normalizer found."
}
```

I guess it's trying to create an entity out of it, but that's not what it is. I just want the damn JSON object as it is.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: on top of the class file you need to call `namespace Drupal\rest\Plugin\rest\resource;`

Comment: I removed my answer while I rethink it. Adding a comment here instead to mention that the answer was about the `serialization_class` part of the plugin definition. This may be necessary or maybe adding the default symfony normalizer as a tagged service.